# How to search for documents containing objects with specific values in a nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is the document structure

```
{
    someProp: 'string value',
    options:{
      environment: [{value: 'Gym'}, {value:'Water'}, {value: 'Home', label:'other string'}]
    }
}
```

I need to filter all documents where `options.environment` contains `{value: 'Gym'}` and `{value: 'Water'}`.

What is the best way to make this query using mongodb aggregate `$match` or another strategy (`$unwind`/`$group`, `$map`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) query operator to do this:

```
{
    "options.environment.value": {
        "$all": ["Gym", "Water"]
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, MongoDB flattens the structure before running a query. In your case, that means that you are effectively searching a document shaped like this:

```
{
    "someProp": "string value",
    "options": {
        "environment": {
            "value": ["Gym", "Water", "Home"],
            "label": ["other string"]
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the opposite behavior, then you can use the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) query operator.

None of this is specific to the Aggregation Framework, so you can use a regular find operation if you don't need any other Aggregation Framework features.